# Nautilus auto refresh issue

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gtk

After update to last version of Ubuntu, Nautilus not work correct. It not automatically refresh, if I delete or replace file. It need press CTRL+R to correct display. On video I press „delete“ and CTRL+R
https://youtu.be/cZTsnvl1ak4

My bug reports are here:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/3006
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/2024148

Is it bug or not?
How it it possible repair?
My version of nautilus is 1:44.0. Help me if I update to version  1:44.0? I tried update to version  1:44.1, but not successfully.
How to update to version 44.1?

Last version of nautilus is 44.1, link here
https://apps.gnome.org/sk/app/org.gnome.Nautilus/

How to update GTK?
If I install GTK 4, can I uninstal GTK 3?

---

**Update: I found solution. During login into Ubuntu choose "Ubuntu", not "Ubuntu Xorg"**

Comment: I use only "Ubuntu", but it still does not auto-refresh